# Fix for google api java sample for latitude anyone?

Tags: java, google-api

I just checked out the google-api-java-client samples and built them using eclipse maven.

I customized my `ClientCredentials` class with the consumer key, consumer secret and enter key.

When i run the sample, it asks me for authorization to access my google latitude data and closes the browser and the eclipse console is left with this error:

```
2011-05-21 23:57:01.777:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2011-05-21 23:57:01.778:INFO::jetty-6.1.24
2011-05-21 23:57:01.792:INFO::Started SocketConnector@localhost:51514
Created new window in existing browser session.
2011-05-21 23:57:09.121:INFO::Stopped SocketConnector@localhost:51514
Current location:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:72)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:450)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:249)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseAndClose(JsonParser.java:176)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseAndClose(JsonParser.java:115)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.JsonCParser.parse(JsonCParser.java:49)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:261)
    at com.google.api.client.sample.latitude.model.LocationResource.executeGetCurrentLocation(LocationResource.java:78)
    at com.google.api.client.sample.latitude.LatitudeSample.showCurrentLocation(LatitudeSample.java:50)
    at com.google.api.client.sample.latitude.LatitudeSample.main(LatitudeSample.java:34)
```

When i debug the application these are the variables on line 450 of JsonParser.class:

```
newInstance null    
isMap   false   
token   JsonToken  (id=40)  
name    "VALUE_STRING" (id=55)  
ordinal 5   
field   Field  (id=45)  
fieldClass  Class<T> (java.lang.Long) (id=47)
```

Field is:

```
public java.lang.Long com.google.api.client.sample.latitude.model.LocationResource.timestampMs
```

This is the HG summary:

```
bob@computer:~/development/google-api-java-client-samples$ hg summary
parent: 92:4be51d2cc385 tip
 Samples for version 1.4.
branch: default
commit: 1 modified
update: (current)
```

**UPDATE!**
This can be fixed by changing com.google.api.client.sample.latitude.model.LocationResource line 30 from "public Long timestampMs;" to "public String timestampMs;". Since the server sends back a string not a number.

The real question is: Why does the server send back a string when the sample expects a number? Is the sample code wrong? (probably) or the server?